# Docker swarm over IPv6

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I'm trying to run Docker Swarm on 3 nodes having IPv6 addresses.

While creating the swarm, I stated the IPv6 address as advertise address, and now having the logs on all 3 nodes full of these messages:

> Mar 24 22:17:10 cmd dockerd[3463]: time="2017-03-24T22:17:10.183319197Z" level=error msg="Failed to join memberlist [*IPv6 address here*] on retry: 1 error(s) occurred:\n\n* Failed to resolve *IPv6 address here*: too many colons in address *IPv6 address here*"

At the same time, the worker nodes joined the cluster and stacks are deployed (well, the overlay network does not function as expected but it might be a separate question)